# MySQL ordering list of users acording to last sent messages

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database called 'users' and 'message'.

**users**:

```
**id** .  **fname**  . **lname**

`1` . `paul` . `jackson`
`2` . `raj` . `krish`
`3` . `john` . `philip`
```

**message**:

```
**fromId** . **toId** . **sdate** . **txt**


`2` . `1` . `100` . `hi paul`
`2` . `1` . `99` . `hey`
`3` . `1` . `91` . `come on`
`2` . `1` . `56` . `are you there?`
`3` . `1` . `32` . `long time`
```

I want to be able to select the list of users who have sent a message to `1`, and the last message sent to `1` on each of the returned row from `users`, and order by the user who sent the last message descending.

**E.g**:

Message from `raj krish` "hi paul".

Message from `john Philip` "come on".

So I was able to retrieve the list of user who have sent a message to `1` and also each last messages. But the problem is that, I can't order the list according to the last messaged user.

I'm really a newbie to `SQL`. Here is the code I tried:

```
$query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM users 
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM message 
    WHERE users.id = message.fromId AND message.toId = 1) 
    ODER BY (SELECT sdate from message 
    ORDER BY sdate DESC 
    LIMIT 1) DESC")

while($usrs = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    $mquery = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM message 
        WHERE fromId = " . $usrs["id"] . " AND toId = 1 
        ORDER BY sdate DESC 
        LIMIT 1");

    while($msg = mysqli_fetch_array($mquery, MYSQLI_BOTH){
        ...... Do some return here! .......

    }
}
```

How do I order the list of `users` with the last message sent by each to `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to solve problems like this in steps, like first recover the users, then make the complete join, then filter the join results, ect...

I'll give you a simple solution that hope it helps!

*v1.0 - No final sorting*

```
SELECT fname, lname, txt FROM users as u
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT fromId, sdate, txt FROM message GROUP BY fromId ORDER BY sdate desc
) m
ON u.Id = m.fromId
```

This `INNER JOIN` is very simple like the 101 of making joins with a minor change. Instead of joining the table itself I make a subquery with the suitable records that you want to join with.

Please tell me if anything isn't clear for you.

### EDIT:

In response to your comment. That's cannot be true. The `GROUP BY` would take care of it. I replicate your example and test it, here are the results:
[image]

### EDIT 2:

You are right! The rows returned arent order by the last message time!
You need to order the join result as well.

*v2.0 - With final sorting*

```
SELECT fname, lname, txt, sdate FROM users as u
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT fromId, sdate, txt FROM message GROUP BY fromId ORDER BY sdate desc
) m
ON u.Id = m.fromId
ORDER BY sdate desc
```

And if you don't want to get `sdate` in the returning tableset you can make a subset of the results with another subquery:

*v3.0 - With final sorting and projection results*

```
SELECT fname, lname, txt FROM
(
SELECT fname, lname, txt, sdate FROM users as u
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT fromId, sdate, txt FROM message GROUP BY fromId ORDER BY sdate desc
) m
ON u.Id = m.fromId
ORDER BY sdate desc
) r
```

Comment: But returns more than 1 for each user. Do you have any idea how to make it display only the last message of each users?

Comment: I make an update. I don't see anything wrong are you completly sure that you are using the exact query posted in the answer?

Comment: After using the `GROUP BY`, the messages doesn't display according to the last sent date but displays according to the sender id.\

Comment: If you're using the `GROUP BY` statement, the `ORDER BY` statement won't take effect anymore.

Comment: @AkrilBH That thing you just said abour `GROUP BY`isn't true `ORDER BY` don't get "override" because of grouping. That `ORDER BY` applies to the joined query and not on the global query, but nothing more. I make an update, check it out!

Comment: @AkrilBH I tried that indeed, I uses to check my answers hehe :P Glad to hear that your problem is solved!

Comment: This is what i got when i tried your last option: error: Every derived table must have its own alias. Are you sure you've tested that?

Comment: But I've fixed it almost the same way you suggest. a moment I'll post here what I've tried so far.

Comment: This is your last suggestion. It's from my main database I'm using to test this: `"SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM users AS u INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM message GROUP BY ref ORDER BY sdate DESC) m ON u.id = m.ref)  WHERE (sto='$idst') AND (todeleted ='false') ORDER BY sdate DESC"`. check if i have any errors.

Comment: @AkrilBH I make an update to "tag" the code samples with version numbers. If you look closely to sample v3.0 you would see a final `r`, is an alias for the query and is needed to avoid the error you have. So, using `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM users AS u INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM message GROUP BY ref ORDER BY sdate DESC) m ON u.id = m.ref) r WHERE (sto='$idst') AND (todeleted ='false') ORDER BY sdate DESC` should get rid of the error. But! Since you are no projecting the results and returning `*` you don't need to use sample `v3.0` and you could try sample `v2.0`

Comment: Got it now. i thought the `r` was a piece of error while typing. It works perfectly now. Thanks alot.